# How to use multiple functions in an api route?

Tags: node.js, api, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use this Api GET Route to find all the players from the authenticated users team. I feel like the const variables are correct but im unsure if what i'm doing is possible as within .then() im using async function so that i can use sync await however I receive findTeam is undefined

auth used in the route is my jwt middleware which is allows me to user req.user.id middleware to get the authenticated user id.

```
router.get('/Team', auth, async function(req, res) {
  //get USers team
  const findTeam = await TeamUsers.findOne({
    where: {
      UserID: req.user.id
    }
  })
    .then(findTeam, async function(req, res) {
      const findTeamID = findTeam.TeamID;

      const findUsers = await TeamUsers.findAll({
        // get the players teamUSers get that Id then
        where: {
          TeamID: findTeamID
        }
      });
    })
    .then(findUsers, async function(req, res) {
      const findUsers = await Users.findByPk(findUsers.id);

      console.log(findUsers.first_name);
      res.status(200).json(findUsers);
    })

    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send('unable to save to database');
    });
});
```

Comment: Promise.then (success, failure) then takes two functions first for success call back and second for failure call back function so in case of you need to use then you have to pass next async function to first parameter and pass data param not req,res

Comment: Please check this https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for then

You can write all code without then  and it will run synchronously 
But you have to check if the function returns value not thrown an exception by checking reference

```
const findTeam = await TeamUsers.findOne({
                            where: {
                                UserID: req.user.id
                            }
                        });

if(findTeam){

    const findTeamID = findTeam.TeamID;    
    const findUsers = await TeamUsers.findAll({
                // get the players teamUSers get that Id then
                                where: {
                                    TeamID: findTeamID
                                }
                            });

    if (findUsers) { ...etc } 

}
```

You can catch exceptions by try catch block or chain functions with catch callback